# Why does Json.writes[T] require an `apply` method?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have some case classes that extend this class:

```
class CitySuggestion(val name: String, val locationId: String, val locationKind: String)
```

I wanted to use `Json.writes[CitySuggestion]` as a JSON writer for this class, so I defined an `unapply` method in its companion object:

```
object CitySuggestion {
  def unapply(cs: CitySuggestion): Option[(String, String, String)] =
    Some((cs.name, cs.locationId, cs.locationKind))
}
```

I thought this would suffice, but the compiler now asks for an `apply` method as well:

> No apply function found 
>   [error]     implicit lazy val citySuggestionWrites = Json.writes[CitySuggestion]

Why does it need an apply method? I don't want to deserialize the JSON, and I would have to add logic to figure out which subclass's instance it should be deserialized to.

Comment: If you make `CitySuggestion` a case class you won't need to manually define either method, though your use case might prevent that.

Comment: @greggory.hz thanks, I can't make it a case class because I'm extending that class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because Play Json's `writes` & `reads` macros share a [common implementation.](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/a751a6739b99368b68771abdcb78271bfab5ac29/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsMacroImpl.scala#L83) Within this implementation the type `A` provided to `Json.writes[A]` is inspected for it's apply method, which in turn is used to generate the apply for the `Writes` instance.

As an alternative to using the 'writes' macro, you can create just roll your own `Write[CitySuggestion]` like this:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

implicit val citySuggestionWrites: Writes[CitySuggestion] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
  (JsPath \ "locationId").write[String] and
  (JsPath \ "locationKind").write[String]
)(unlift(CitySuggestion.unapply))
```